# No Suitable constructor found for File(file)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been getting there error:

```
    error: no suitable constructor found for File(File)
            File file = new File(testFile);
                        ^
constructor File.File(String,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor File.File(String,File) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor File.File(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to String)
constructor File.File(String,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor File.File(File,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor File.File(URI) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to URI)
```

I do not understand what the error is telling me, could someone please explain?
This is my code:

```
    public ShortenWord( File testFile ) {
    try {
        File file = new File(testFile);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

        List originalWords = new List();
        List abbWords = new List();

        while (in.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(",");
            String originalWord = parts[0];
            String abbWord = parts[1];
        }
    }
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Any help on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated. As I don't have a clue
:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File constructor expect File pathname as String for single parameter. You shouldn't pass another file object at File constructor.

```
File file = new File("somefilename.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `File` class has no constructor with a `File` argument (also known as a copy constructor).

If you already pass a `File` to the `ShortenWord` constructor, just use it instead of trying to create a new `File` :

```
public ShortenWord( File testFile ) {
  try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(testFile);

    List originalWords = new List();
    List abbWords = new List();

    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        String originalWord = parts[0];
        String abbWord = parts[1];
    }
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
      System.out.println(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

There is 4 constructor and none of them take a File as a parameter:

```
File(File parent, String child)
Creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and a child pathname string.
File(String pathname)
Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname.
File(String parent, String child)
Creates a new File instance from a parent pathname string and a child pathname string.
File(URI uri)
Creates a new File instance by converting the given file: URI into an abstract pathname.
```

Try using a String as parameter.